# Fade in SVG background image

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have this problem fading in from one icon to another with SVG sprites as a background image when hovered over.

```
#About1 a {
    background: url(../_images/Center_Nav.svg) no-repeat center -788px;
}

#About1 a:hover {
    background: url(../_images/Center_Nav.svg) no-repeat center -888px;
}
```

I have tried different methods found on the web but nothing works, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have two images both visible one on top of another (so you only see the top one).

On hover, decrease the opacity of the top image.

```
.fade {
   transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
}

.fade:hover {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

Something like this (though you may also need -webkit-animation for Chrome/Opera/Safari) with the top image having a class of "fade"

Comment: How would you put that into code also adding a specific timing for the fading?